# Why do I need to recast an integer array accessed from within an object array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have following code that makes an Object array and passes two integer arrays into it. Then, I want to set another integer array variable to one of the arrays inside the object array.

However, unless I perform the (int[]) type casting step, I get an error. Why do I need to perform this re-casting? I would assume that the arrays inside the object are int[] since that's how they were passed.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4};
        int[] arr2 = {4,5,6};

        Object[] x = {arr1, arr2};

        int[] left =(int[]) x[0];

        for (int element : left){
            System.out.println(element);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` are of type `int[]`, but when you store them in an array of type `Object[]` you hide their true type. You could declare `x` to be of type `int[][]`, then no cast would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x is an array of Objects.

Therefore one element of that array is an Object.

x[0] is an Object.

That it is also an int[] is not something the language knows.  A bag of Objects lets you put pretty much any type of thing in the bag, but the bag is not obliged to remember the specific type of each thing. When you pull a thing out of the bag, all that is known about it is that it is an Object, because that's what the bag was declared to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Object class is the superclass of all of the classes in Java. So when you are passing an int array to Object type, then it is received as Object type. Now the Object array has two elements of Object. They are integer also, no doubt. But to your variable **x** they are Object.

Now when you are retrieving the elements, then you need to cast to int, as they are Object to **x**.

You can refer any subclass object to its superclass reference. But when you will retrieve the subclass object again from its superclass reference, you need to cast this. As your superclass reference doesn't know which subclass type of it.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should answer your question

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    String[] arr2 = { "a", "b", "c" };

    Object[] x = { arr1, arr2 };

    int[] left = (int[]) x[0];
    for (int element : left) {
      System.out.println(element);
    }
  }
```

When you push arr1, arr2 into another array of Object[] type, the compiler doesn't assume the type of elements in Object[] x array, as it can accept arrays of any type. That is why  the compiler forces you to cast the elements used from Object[] array x.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me explain some point about java:

- Object.java is the mother of all objects in java
- Java has feature called autoboxing,and autounboxing

```java
Object[] x = {arr1, arr2};
```

when you assign this, java compiler will :

- automatically autobox arr1,arr2 to Integer[] (the wrapper one)
- then ,as Object is the mother of all object in java, it simply conver the Integer[] to Object[]

thats why you need to recast it to primitive int[],
as variable x is already Object[]

hope this helps you